# QGLWidget Rendering The surrounding widgets

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

This problem is exceedingly difficult to explain, I can't even think of a word to explain this phenomenon so I will just show you a picture.

[image]

On the far left is the actual dockwidget, and where its all overlapping is an openGL widget, which is supposed to be drawing blue and a tree. But it isn't.

What is this problem even called and how do I fix it?

I should also add that when there is no dockwidget involved it works perfectly.

EDIT: New information, after profiling the app in an openGL profiler I have discovered that when the dock widget is used, CGLUpdateContext is never called for some reason, and every single gl call results in an error `GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATIO`N I also found the error `invalid drawable` appearing in the console.

Further research shows this might be bug in Qt. I shall look into it more.

EDIT2: I have put in this check before initializing openGL and calling glClear, which is where the first error is thrown.

```
GLenum er = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if(er != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    abort();
}
```

When a dock widget is used, this aborts at this point, telling us the frame buffer is incomplete. However, if I remove the dock widget, this does not abort and the app works fine.
I now know that the frame buffer is incomplete, but why? This is a problem with Qt not my code.

Comment: Our app uses a game engine behind the scenes that has thousands of lines, I have not got any idea what code is the problem

Comment: I have discovered that when the QGLWidget is the only widget and the centralWidget it works. But never in any other situation